# Is there a way to take picture outside would encounters?

Tags: pokemon-go

I'd like to take some pictures using the Pokémon I've captured, like having a weedle in my soup or an ekans in my boot.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: This might possibly me rolled out in later phases. But I'd rather have proper dueling and trading first. :D

Answer (score 2):

## This is currently not implemented.

Nor do we have any information that it will. For now, the only possibility to create a picture with a Poké on it natively is when you encounter it and try to catch it, enable AR.

Otherwise you might also screenshot them, use software like [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/), cut them out and place them over another photo. :)